# pip installing to wrong folder even though `which pip` is correct

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, homebrew

I'm using Mac OS X 10.10. I want to use pip to install packages for my homebrew installed version of python (located in `/usr/local/bin/python`, which is an alias that points to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`). It appears that site-packages for this version are here: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.

`which python` returns `/usr/local/bin/python`

`which pip` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip`

These seem correct to me.

Trying something like `pip install pylzma` returns:

```
Collecting pylzma
Installing collected packages: pylzma
Successfully installed pylzma
You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But then `pip list` does not show `pylzma` to be installed. It looks like pip installs the packages to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (the python that ships with Mac OS X).

How can I get pip to install to my homebrewed python?

I've tried a number of suggestions from similar questions:

1. I've tried `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/python:${PATH}`.
2. I've tried `pip install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local/lib/python2.7" pylzma`.
3. I've tried changing the first line of the pip executable script to `#!/usr/local/bin/python`
4. I've tried `/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install pylzma`.

But none of these work. I also tried upgrading pip to 8.1.1, but that made pip break entirely. People recommend using `virtualenv`, but as far as I know, I can't install that without pip.

When I type `python -m pip`, it says:

```
Usage:
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -m pip <command> [options]
```

Could that be a problem?

Comment: "I've tried /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install pylzma.". But did you remove the installation in `/Library/...` before that. Otherwise that one might interfere.

Comment: Also check that `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` exists, or whether things get installed in `/usr/local/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages` instead. Sometimes, Homebrew doesn't create the symlink from `/usr/local/opt/python/` to `/usr/local/`.

Comment: @Evert, I've read that it is not recommended to remove the Mac OS X python installation in `/Library/...`.

Comment: I may have fixed this. I changed the `install_dir` in my .pydistutils.cfg file from `install_dir = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to `install_dir = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Pip now installs to the correct folder. However I still get an ImportError when I do `import pylzma`. That may be a specific issue with pylzma...?

Comment: @Evert, `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` does exist. I'm having ongoing issues: when I try running `jupyter notebook`, I get `ImportError: No module named markupsafe` even though `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23.dist-info` exists. Maybe I need to start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that my `/Users/<username>/.pydistutils.cfg` contained the following:

```
[easy_install]

# set the default location to install packages
install_dir = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

[install]
install_lib = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
install_scripts = ~/bin
```

I changed this to:

```
[easy_install]
# set the default location to install packages
install_dir = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

[install]
install_lib = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
install_scripts = ~/bin
```

That seemed to have worked. `pip install` now installs packages to the desired location `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

However, I am have ongoing path issues.

`import pylzma` still gives me `ImportError: No module named pylzma`.

and running `jupyter notebook` in terminal gives `-bash: jupyter: command not found`. `/Users/<username>/bin/jupyter notebook` does execute, but I get `ImportError: No module named markupsafe` despite the fact that `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23.dist-info` exists.

EDIT: I got jupyter notebook working eventually. I had to install several packages from the source tarballs directly, including MarkupSafe, functools32, and jsonschema. Maybe Python is not looking in the correct folder or something.

Comment: Almost all packages are installed as pairs of directories, e.g. .../MarkupSafe-0.23-py2.7.egg-info/ and .../site-packages/markupsafe/ . Do you have both ? If not, look for a directory markupsafe somewhere else, e.g. `cd .../site-packages; du | egrep markupsafe` .